# Solucionar exception: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, scraping

Estoy haciendo un programa que obtiene los posts de TikTok de un usuario. Sin embargo, el programa no funciona correctamente y me salta este error: IndexError: list index out of range. El programa ha sido probado con VPN ya que al usarlo con mi IP propia, aparece un error diferente. Se agradece toda solución posible.

El error completo es:

```
  File "F:\Escritorio\Tiktok Post Remove\get_posts.py", line 123, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Escritorio\Tiktok Post Remove\get_posts.py", line 120, in main
    getUserInfo(usn)
  File "F:\Escritorio\Tiktok Post Remove\get_posts.py", line 47, in getUserInfo
    secID = obj.split('secUid":"')[1].split('"')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Este es el código completo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.parse import urlencode

userID = ""
secID = ""
count = ""
videos = []
def base36encode(number, alphabet="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"):
    base36 = ""
    sign = ""

    if number < 0:
        sign = "-"
        number = -number

    if 0 <= number < len(alphabet):
        return sign + alphabet[number]

    while number != 0:
        number, i = divmod(number, len(alphabet))
        base36 = alphabet[i] + base36

    return sign + base36
def gen_verifyFp():
    chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[:]
    chars_len = len(chars)
    scenario_title = base36encode(int(time.time() * 1000))
    uuid = [0] * 36
    uuid[8] = "_"
    uuid[13] = "_"
    uuid[18] = "_"
    uuid[23] = "_"
    uuid[14] = "4"

    for i in range(36):
        if uuid[i] != 0:
            continue
        r = int(random.random() * chars_len)
        uuid[i] = chars[int((3 & r) | 8 if i == 19 else r)]

    return f'verify_{scenario_title.lower()}_{"".join(uuid)}'
def getUserInfo(username):
    global userID
    global secID
    obj = requests.get('https://www.tiktok.com/@' + username, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.66'}).text
    secID = obj.split('secUid":"')[1].split('"')[0]
    userID = obj.split('userId":"')[1].split('"')[0]
    print('Fetched user info.')

def setup():
    global videos
    verifyFp = gen_verifyFp()
    did = str(random.randint(10000, 999999999))
    query1 = {
        "aid": 1988,
        "app_name": "tiktok_web",
        "device_platform": "web",
        "referer": "",
        "root_referer": "",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.66",
        "cookie_enabled": "true",
        "screen_width": "1920",
        "screen_height": "1080",
        "browser_language": "en-US",
        "browser_platform": "Win32",
        "browser_name": "Mozilla",
        "browser_version": "5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.66",
        "browser_online": "true",
        "ac": "4g",
        "timezone_name": "Australia/Sydney",
        "appId": 1233,
        "appType": "m",
        "isAndroid": False,
        "isMobile": False,
        "isIOS": False,
        "OS": "windows"
    }
    query = {
        "count": str(count),
        "id": userID,
        "cursor": 0,
        "type": 1,
        "secUid": secID,
        "sourceType": 8,
        "appId": 1233,
        "region": "au",
        "priority_region": "au",
        "language": "en",
    }
    url = "https://m.tiktok.com/api/post/item_list/?{}&{}".format(urlencode(query1), urlencode(query))
    signed_url = sign(url)
    obj = requests.get(signed_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.66'}).json()
    for item in obj['itemList']:
        videos.append(item['id'])
    print("Fetched videos.")
def sign(url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1400x1080")
    options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    driver.execute_script(acrawler.get_acrawler())
    result = driver.execute_script('''
        var token = window.byted_acrawler.sign({url: "''' + url + '''"});
        return token;
    ''')
    return url + "&_signature=" + result

def main():
    global count
    usn = input("Username: ")
    count = input("Count: ")
    getUserInfo(usn)
    setup()

main()
```

*Muchas gracias. Espero que este codigo también les sirva a algunos interesados en TikTok.*
Por si a alguno tambien le interesa, este es el error que sale con mi IP normal:
[image: Imágen]

Comment: Estar tratando de acceder a u  índice que no existe. Recuerda que si no se encuentra el carácter al momento de hacer el split , este regresa una lista con un solo elemento por lo que `obj.split('secUid":"')[1]` dará error si no se encuentra `secUid":"`

Comment: @Christian Hola, he publicado una actualización en este post. Gracias por la ayuda, me di cuenta y puse un print para ver si al menos obtenía los datos correctamente. Tmabién me di cuenta de que era un .text... Ahora me sale un nuevo error desafortunandamente.